# PDF to HTML in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, pdf, uiwebview

Is it possible to convert a PDF page in to HTML format using any objective-c library. I want to enable the text selection on PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

@swiecki approach is not valid for pdfs

My suggestion is to use CoreText and add an overlay over the pdf view.
But it will be a long and tedious process as you need to parse the pdf to find coordinates of every letter.

Comment: Hey Mac can i use mobfarm pdf kit in my app.I want to know that apple store will approve my application or not.Just help me in that

Comment: We (and other developers) have many app already on the App Store that are using that library.